# Flutter local_auth dialog closes if authentication fails

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth library to implement `local_auth` in my app.

I am using the following code to authenticate.

```
  Future<void> _authenticate() async {
    bool authenticated = false;
    try {
      authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
          localizedReason: 'Scan your fingerprint to authenticate');

      print('Authentitcated: $authenticated');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

If authentication is `success` it shows `Authenticated: true` but it does not show anything if authentication fails. Also, the authentication dialogue closes automatically if authentication fails.

How do I return the authentication `false` status also keep the dialogue open even after authentication is failed?

Comment: You are not _returning_ anything from this method.

Comment: @Styx Yes. I know that. But the print should work even if I am not returning anything.

Comment: Actually, no. It should work if: 1) authenticate complete; 2) you caught `PlatformException` error. What if there is another type of error?

Comment: There is no other `Exception`. The program waits at `authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
          localizedReason: 'Scan your fingerprint to authenticate');`

Comment: same issue i am facing right now. Xihuny did you got solution for it?